# Rails: Can I disable the better_errors gem in certain domains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activeadmin, better-errors-gem

ActiveAdmin and the better_errors gem don't play nice. Any rendering error makes the Rails server seize up and eat all my cpu, requiring a `kill -9` to get out of the death-spin and pick the pieces up. Is there a way to conditionally use better_errors in one part of my app without using it in the part where ActiveAdmin lives?

Answer (score 0):

In my example I prepare lib/middleware/better_errors_patch.rb.

```
if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
  require 'better_errors'

  module BetterErrors
    class Middleware
      def call(env)
        if allow_ip?(env) && !env['PATH_INFO'].match(%r{\/admin\/})
          better_errors_call env
        else
          @app.call env
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I resolve it by this monkey_patch. First, set `gem 'better_errors', require: false` in your Gemfile.Then you add `require './lib/middleware/ex_better_errors'` in application.rb scope. It works for me.